# python client can't connect to elasticsear remotely

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

This code works perfectly on my machine which has the exact same elasticsearh version as the server,

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
        es = Elasticsearch(['the server ip is here'], port=9200) 

        body = json.dumps(itemDictionary, ensure_ascii=True)
        es.index(index = 'indexname', doc_type = 'doc', body = body)
```

I am getting this error

```
WARNING:elasticsearch:POST http://the ip of the server:9200/indexname/doc [status:N/A request:0.197s]

es.index(index = 'indexname', doc_type = 'doc', body = body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 261, in index
    _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 89, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10cc62550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10cc62550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused)
```

the python version is 2.7 and the elastcisearch version is 2.1.1

Comment: Silly question, but is the server listening on that IP address, or is it listening on localhost?

Comment: @SimonFraser i didnt get u sorry could u repeat?

Comment: Your server (like other computers) will have the network address you're using (the 'server ip' in your question) and also 127.0.0.1 (or 'localhost') which is only reachable from the server itself. This is so network services continue without a 'real' network. By default, elasticsearch only listens on localhost, and isn't reachable from other computers. This is a common practice, as it lets you test things and set up security without it being reachable from anywhere else.